# Getting error on creating pdf using mpdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

If anyone have any idea about [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) image error please share here.

mPDF error: `***IMAGE Error (https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=500x350&chds=0,3500&chxt=x,y,y&chxr=1,0,3500,500&chxl=1:|0|500|1,000|1,500|2,000|2,500|3,000|3,500|0:|Budget%20with%20no%20conversions|Budget%20with%20conversions|2:|Cost%20()&chxp=2,50&chco=FFC100&chg=0,14.285714285714,1,3,0,0&chm=N*sf0*,000000,0,,12,0,be:0:5&chbh=a&chd=t:1055.1,3439.69): Could not find image file***`

I'm already on curl in my system using => 
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
 and 
sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Have you tried using the non-https-URL? Or if you have to use https-urls you could try add `stream_context_set_default(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false)));` before any mPDF-call.

Comment: Its not working for me =>

stream_context_set_default(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false)));

Comment: Have you tried using `http` instead of `https`? Is there a firewall which might Block outgoing HTTP(S)-Requests from the host which runs your code?